# How to factorize $2x^2 + 2x + 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics, completing-the-square

How to factorize $2x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0$ into $2(x + 0.5)^2 + 0.5$ ?

What is the process behind this factorization?

Edit: Thanks guys, have updated this post. Updated the tag to complete the square.

Comment: See [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's $$2\left(x^2+x+\frac{1}{2}\right)=2\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}\right)=2\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 4):

I believe you mean $2x^2+2x+1 = 2((x+0.5)^2+0.5^2)$.

This is not a factorization, this is completing the square.

A factorization would be in the form
$$ax^2+bx+c=k(px+q)(rx+s)$$

Notice that there are no leftover terms, including constants.

Answer (score 1):

In $ \mathbb C$:

The zeros of $2z^2+2z+1$ are $z_1= \frac{1}{2}(-1+i)$ and $z_2 = \overline{z_1}.$

Hence we have the factorization

$$2z^2+2z+1=2(z-z_1)(z-z_2).$$